# Convert types via string using SWIG typemaps

Tags: python, c++, ruby, type-conversion, swig

I am using swig to generate wrapper for some classes. One class takes a list of QUuid (std::list) (see below). There is a toString which gives a std::string and python also can instantiate its uuid by using this string. How can I generate a typemap (or maybe something else might be better) which uses the convertion described above to python and vice versa. Best would be if that is independent of the target language as well (at least I will need ruby wrappers as well).

Thanks

IRPICurrentPositionsCommand.h:

```
class IRPICurrentPositionsCommand : public CommandBase
{
  Q_OBJECT

  COMMAND_IMPLEMENTATION_BASICS(IRPICurrentPositionsCommand, ir)

public:
  std::list<QUuid> GetAxisIDs() const
  {
    return m_AxisIDs;
  }

  void SetAxisIDs(std::list<QUuid> arg)
  {
    m_AxisIDs = arg;
  }

  std::list<double> GetAxisPostions() const
  {
    return m_AxisPostions;
  }

  void SetAxisPostions(std::list<double> arg)
  {
    m_AxisPostions = arg;
  }

private:
  std::list<QUuid> m_AxisIDs;
  std::list<double> m_AxisPostions;

protected:

  /** @see ora::CommandBase::Serialize(QDataStream &stream) **/
  virtual void Serialize(QDataStream &stream) const;

  /** @see ora::CommandBase::Deserialize(QDataStream &stream) **/
  virtual void Deserialize(QDataStream &stream);
};
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you post your .h please?

Comment: @MasterMind I added an exmaple header.

Comment: So basically you want to know how to generate templates for your `std::list<QUuid>` objects?

Comment: @MasterMind That is exactly what I want to have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SWIG/Python template for the `std::list<QUuid>` objects. I'm not familiar with Ruby, but hopefully this will give you some insights into typemaps.

```
// To use std::string
%include "std_string.i"

%typemap(out) std::list<QUuid>
{
    PyObject* outList = PyList_New(0);

    int error;

    std::list<QUuid>::iterator it;
    for ( it=$1.begin() ; it != $1.end(); it++ )
    {
        PyObject* pyQUuid = SWIG_NewPointerObj(new QUuid(*it), SWIGTYPE_p_QUuid, SWIG_POINTER_OWN );

        error = PyList_Append(outList, pyQUuid);
        Py_DECREF(pyQUuid);
        if (error) SWIG_fail;       
    }

    $result = outList;
}

%typemap(in) std::list<QUuid>
{
    //$input is the PyObject
    //$1 is the parameter

    if (PyList_Check($input))
    {
        std::list<QUuid> listTemp;

        for(int i = 0; i<PyList_Size($input); i++)
        {
            PyObject* pyListItem = PyList_GetItem($input, i);

            QUuid* arg2 = (QUuid *) 0 ;

            int res1 = 0;
            void *argp1;

            res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(pyListItem, &argp1, SWIGTYPE_p_QUuid,  0  | 0);
            if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1))
            {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"List must only contain QUuid objects");
                return NULL;
            }  
            if (!argp1)
            {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Invalid null reference for object QUuid");
                return NULL;
            }

            arg2 = reinterpret_cast< QUuid * >(argp1);
            listTemp.push_back(*arg2);
        }

        $1 = listTemp;
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Wrong argument type, list expected");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to add that to my wrapper.

Comment: Two questions: 1 .How can I get the definition of SWIGTYPE_p_QUuid? It only shows up if I have a function which takes QUuid as parameter. 
2. Where is the part where I tell python that it should us UUID?